# Search Replace value in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, replace

I am new in XSLT and need some help,
I am getting an Original XML below which I need to transform as a Transformed XML

Original

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML payloadID="121" timestamp="2022-09-12" version="1.2.031" xml:lang="en-US">
<Header>
<From>
<Login domain="RollID">
<Value>ABC12100</Value>
</Login>
<Login domain="NameID">
<Value>BOB</Value>
</Login>
<Login domain="CourseID">
<Value>Default</Value>
</Login>
</From>
<Header>
<OrderID>
<OrderHeaderID sampleID="sdhjgwsd" orderDate="TEST-2022-09-12T21:30:31+02:00" orderID="66625" orderType="regular" orderVersion="1" type="new">
</OrderID>
</cXML>
```

Transformed XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML payloadID="121" timestamp="2022-09-12" version="1.2.031" xml:lang="en-US">
<Header>
<From>
<Login domain="RollID">
<Value>ABC12100_TEST</Value>
</Login>
<Login domain="NameID">
<Value>BOB</Value>
</Login>
<Login domain="CourseID">
<Value>Default</Value>
</Login>
</From>
<Header>
<OrderID>
<OrderHeaderID sampleID="sdhjgwsd" orderDate="2022-09-12T21:30:31+02:00" orderID="66625_**TEST**" orderType="regular" orderVersion="1" type="new">
</OrderID>
</cXML>
```

I need value  of  OrderId and cXML/Header/From/Login[@domain='RollID']/**Value** to be appended with TEST as mentioned in transform XML. Please help !!

Comment: A request for someone to write your code for you is not a legitimate question.This is a trivial task; where exactly are you stuck with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a transformation using the identity template to copy everything unchanged, plus a template to transform the selected attributes

```
<xsl:template match="@orderID">
  <xsl:attribute name="orderID"><xsl:value-of select="."/>_**TEST**</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This question does feel rather as if you're launching into using XSLT without having first done some reading. A few hours spent with a book or tutorial would be a good investment of your time.

Also, it's always a good idea in XSLT questions to say whether you're using 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0, since all are in widespread use, and the answers will often vary.